# @expires vs. retract and Memory Management

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

1) I have setup a small program inserting a event to my key session running in STREAM mode. I have created a timer rule causing halt() after 5 seconds. Running this program with fireUntilHalt() and printing kieSession.getFactCount() shows me that there are still 1 fact in the working memory.

2) Next i declare the event with @expires(4s) and run the program again this time there is no facts left in the working memory as expected.

3) Next i created a rule using the temporal condition that no other events has been inserted within 2 seconds causing the rule to retract the event. Again as expected there 0 facts in the working memory as expected.

4) Next i created a rule inserting an event 1 second after the first event. This time only one is retracted because the second event is within 2 seconds of the first one, but Memory Management apparently retracts the first event because it can no longer match any rule due to its temporal constraints. Again there are 0 facts left in the working memory.

> One of the benefits of running the engine in STREAM mode is that the engine can detect when an event can no longer match any rule due to its temporal c onstraints. When that happens, the engine can safely delete the event from the session without side effects and release any resources used by that event.

Through out these 4 tests i added an eventListener(), reporting insertions and retractions and i also set up a logger for the audit view in eclipse.

**My question is: Why does both the eventListener() and the Audit view not report when a fact is expired or handled by the Memory Management system.**

1) In the first test obviously nothing was retracted thus the reports are concise.

2) The second test did not report any retraction, but 0 facts was left in working memory although one fact was inserted.

3) The third test reported a retraction, thus the report are concise.

4) The fourth test reported a retraction but 2 facts was actually "retracted" thus the report was in-concise.

**Does another solution exist to report expired facts and memory management actions??**